# Почему в jQuery.get не нужно указывать тип синхронности передачи данных, т.е true или false

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

```
function getFile() {
  $.get("ajax_1.txt", function(data) {
    $("#text").append(data);
  });
}
```

Как сменить синхронизацию в этом коде?

Comment: потому что async:false - считается deprected

Comment: @Grundy  что такое deprecated?

Comment: `deprecated` - это устаревшее.

Comment: @Grundy т.е там только синхронная, true?

Comment: Наоборот, только асинхронное.

Comment: @Grundy ой, перепутал, сори)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`jQuery.get`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/) является оберткой для вызова [`jQuery.ajax`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

При этом, функция может принимать как набор параметров

1. [`jQuery.get( url [, data ] [, success ] [, dataType ] )`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/#jQuery-get-url-data-success-dataType)

так и объект с настройками:

2. [`jQuery.get( [settings ] )`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/#jQuery-get-settings)

Во втором случае в объект, помимо обязательного поля `url` можно так же добавить поле `async`, которое по умолчанию `true` - то есть, запросы асинхронные по умолчанию.

Кроме того, можно воспользоваться функцией [`jQuery.ajaxSetup`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajaxSetup/) для установки настроек запросов глобально.